# Concise way to declare and load object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I am creating and a function on that object to load data into the various properties. While the method works as desired, I feel like it might be redundant. Can this be accomplished in a more concise or better way?

```
var user = {        
    productLine: {
        userActiveValue: []
    },
    id: {
        PACT: null,
        EDIPI: null,
        AKO: null,
    },
    name: {
        first: null,
        last: null,
    },
    DMIS: null,
    region: null,
    email: null,
    load: true,
    loadUser: function (userInfoAPIResponse) {
        this.id.PACT = userInfoAPIResponse.UID;
        this.id.EDIPI = userInfoAPIResponse.EDIPN;
        this.id.AKO = userInfoAPIResponse.akoUserID;
        this.name.first = userInfoAPIResponse.fName;
        this.name.last = userInfoAPIResponse.lName;
        this.DMIS = userInfoAPIResponse.dmisID;
        this.region = userInfoAPIResponse.RHCName;
        this.email = userInfoAPIResponse.userEmail;
        console.log(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: If you keep a consistency between property names in your object and the property names of the values returned by `userInfoAPIResponse` then all you have to do is run a loop. Also, `loadUser` should be outside the `user` object as an extension of the prototype.

Comment: The object returned by the API is from another department. The naming convention coming from that API is different than what we want to use, and we don't have an option to change it on their end. I wish it could be the same.

Comment: I like Qwertiy's solution, but if you want to stick with an object literal and guarantee that `loadUser` is called before any work is done, then you can eliminate the property definitions above (except for `productLine` and `load`, since you're not assigning those in your `loadUser` function). The rest are being written to when you load the data, and they don't have to be defined first.

Comment: @JoeEnos, or just `var user = new User({});` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function User(userInfoAPIResponse) {
  this.id = {
    PACT: userInfoAPIResponse.UID,
    EDIPI: userInfoAPIResponse.EDIPN,
    AKO: userInfoAPIResponse.akoUserID
  };
  this.productLine = {
    userActiveValue: []
  };
  this.name = {
    first: userInfoAPIResponse.fName,
    last: userInfoAPIResponse.lName
  };
  this.DMIS = userInfoAPIResponse.dmisID;
  this.region = userInfoAPIResponse.RHCName;
  this.email = userInfoAPIResponse.userEmail;
}
```

```
var user = new User(...);
```

Comment: Good idea. I suppose I'd get an undefined if the property doesn't exist on the incoming object in this case?

Comment: @IthinkIcancode, yes. But you code acts in the same way, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using e.g. user.name = {first: response.fName, last: response.lName} and so on, no. You need to map the variables from one object to another yourself, or just use the response as your user variable.
Alternatively you could just declare user as global (or outer) scope and both declare and set the sub-objects in your callback function. This would mean you potentially had to check for them and their parents being undefined before using them elsewhere, as opposed to a simple not null check.

Comment: Seems Quertiy beat me to it with a more full answer